# How to return an object of an element with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some of you the question might sound funny, but I would like to know how is possible to return an object of an element theough browser console so that I could see what methods are assigned to it.

Let's say if I am doing like this:

```
$('.smartmenufloaty')
```

it will bring an array of elements.

```
$('.smartmenufloaty')[0]
```

this will bring up the HTML context of an element, but still not pretty sure what is the main difference of the array and of this HTML context, but what I am looking is how to reveal something like this through console:

```
[div.smartmenufloaty, context: div.smartmenufloaty, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.3.2", size: function…]
```

which holds the information I need. I would appreciate an explanation or a link where I could read more.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `console.log($('.smartmenufloaty'))` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
console.dir($('.smartmenufloaty')[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/56DZe/